# How to write a construction of code as a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, pandas, split-apply-combine

I am new to programming and python and would like to write the following piece of code as a function using the 'def' 'return' construction:

```
df.loc[df['DATE_INT'].shift(-1) - df['DATE_INT'] == 1, 'CONSECUTIVE_DAY'] = True
df.loc[(df['DATE_INT'].shift(-1) - df['DATE_INT'] == 1) | (df['DATE_INT'].shift(1) - df['DATE_INT'] == -1), 'CONSECUTIVE_DAY'] = True
```

My attempt returns invalid syntax:

```
def ConsecutiveID(df, column ='DATE_INT'):
    return  df.loc[df['DATE_INT'].shift(-1) - df['DATE_INT'] == 1, 'CONSECUTIVE_DAY'] = True
            df.loc[(df['DATE_INT'].shift(-1) - df['DATE_INT'] == 1) | (df['DATE_INT'].shift(1) - df['DATE_INT'] == -1), 'CONSECUTIVE_DAY'] = True
```

My goal is to ultimately use my ConsecutiveID function as follows:

```
    df.groupby(['COUNTY_GEOID_YEAR','TEMPBIN']).apply(ConsecutiveID)
```

I am applying the split-apply-combine construction. Where groupby is splitting my data and I use the function I would like to construct in apply.

My main question is how to write what I've called the ConsecutiveID as a function. Thank you for any help.

Comment: don't use `return`, `df` will still be updated in the function. Note, most pandas function require `inplace=true` to actually update the df.

Comment: After the two statements just return the `df`.

Comment: @JulienBernu - Great thank you, that solved the syntax error.. Having other problems applying the function. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: Try just calling `ConstructiveID` on `df`. Btw, convention is to start functions with lower case, capital being for classes...

Comment: @JulienBernu  -- Thank you - its worked and its done exactly what I've wanted it to do! Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ConsecutiveID(df):
    df = df.copy()
    cond1 = df['DATE_INT'].shift(-1) - df['DATE_INT'] == 1
    cond2 = df['DATE_INT'].shift(1) - df['DATE_INT'] == -1

    df.loc[cond1 | cond2, 'CONSECUTIVE_DAY'] = True

    return df
```